# How to send an automatic email or sms from android application?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, sms

I am creating an android application with the android studio in which I want to include the functionality that as soon as a customer places an order and it gets saved in the Firebase database, the user should either get an email regarding the order details or an SMS for the same.

Answer (score 0):

For sending email automatically you can use firebase function which send email by calling its pre-defined URL. I found one example may be this on will help you:
[cloud functions for firebase sending E-mail](https://medium.com/@edigleyssonsilva/cloud-functions-for-firebase-sending-e-mail-1f2631d1022e)